# bug in JavaScript tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

```js
// Winning combos array
const winCombos = [
     [0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8],
     [0, 3, 6],
     [1, 4, 7],
     [2, 5, 8],
     [0, 4, 8],
     [6, 4, 2]
]
//player starts with X
let playerTurn = 'X';
//flag to indicate if game has ended
let gameEnded = false;
//loop through each cell1, cell2, cell3 etc.
for(let i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
 //grab one cell element at a time--when page loads, loop will have run 9 times
 let cell = document.getElementById('c' + i);
     //add listener to each cell
     cell.addEventListener('click', runGame);
     //declare the rungame function
     function runGame() {
          //if game is over or cell is not empty, do nothing
          if(gameEnded===true||cell.innerHTML!=='') {
               return;
          }
          //set cell to playerTurn
          cell.innerHTML = playerTurn;
          //change playerTurn
          switchTurn();
          //check for winner
          if(checkForWin()) {
               alert('game over');
          }
     }
     //declare checkForWin function 
     function checkForWin() {
          //make for loop to grab the 3 values in each seperate array
          for(let i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++) {
               //create 3 variables to hold the 3 indexes of each seperate win combo
               cell1 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][0]);
               cell2 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][1]);
               cell3 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][2]);
               //if all cells match either x or o, game over
               if (cell1.innerHTML===playerTurn
               && cell2.innerHTML===playerTurn
               && cell3.innerHTML===playerTurn) {
                    return true;
               }
          }
          return false;
     }


}
//declare switchTurn function
function switchTurn() {
     if (playerTurn==='X') {
          playerTurn = 'O';
     } else if (playerTurn==='O') {
          playerTurn = 'X';
     }
}
```

```css
td {
 border:  2px solid #333;
 height:  100px;
 width:  100px;
 text-align:  center;
 vertical-align:  middle;
 font-family:  "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 font-size:  70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -155px;
 top: 220px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
 border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
 border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

.endgame {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tic tac toe</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c0" onclick=""></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c1"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c3"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c4"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c6"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c7"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c8"></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="endgame">
   <div class="text">Cant see this text</div>
  </div>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys I'm currently working on a simple Javascript tic tac toe game.
Everything is working good so far except for one thing...
There's a `checkForWin()` function in the main function, this function checks every possible winning combination to see if 'X or 'O' has won.
`if checkForWin() === true then alert('game over');` and it does this but not as soon as you make the winning move, it will only alert on the 'click' after???
*(Question 1)* So say 'X' is lined up diagonally. `alert('game over')` won't run till 'O' clicks on their square. Also when 'O' does this the alert message will show then the letter 'O' will be placed in the square???
Any help would be awesome! thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `switchTurn()` too early. Your `checkForWin()` function is checking against the `playerTurn` character (`X` or `O`) of the *next* player instead of the player that just made a move.

You can rewrite your `runGame()` function as follows:

```
function runGame() {
    if(gameEnded || cell.innerHTML) {
        return;
    }

    cell.innerHTML = playerTurn;

    if(checkForWin()) {
        alert('game over');
    }

    switchTurn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question and after moving the switchTurn(); to the bottom, 
it seems that "alert();" runs before the page is updated (redrawn by the browser) with the X or O. Try using a different message like this:

```
function showMessage() {
    var msg = document.createElement("div");
    msg.innerHTML = "GAME OVER!"
    msg.classList.add("message");
    document.body.appendChild(msg);
    gameEnded = true;
}
```

And add a class to the message:

```
.message {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -155px;
    top: 220px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

I hope it helps!